# Correct permissions for OS X El capitan's user directory etc?

Tags: macos, permissions

a friend of mine played with my mac and set `chmod 0755` on `/` (I disabled SIP).

Now the Guest user can see every document on my filesystem and so everybody having physical access to my MacBook would be able to copy my stuff onto another machine.

Both starting the "first aid" function of El Capitan and upgrading to 10.11.3 didn't help.

I'm a bit scared of setting `0700` on `/Users`.

Could an El Capitan user with correct permissions run `cd /; ls -lah` and paste the results?
Could the same be done for `/Users` and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already restored perms on the standard packages?
`sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /`
If not, that might save a lot of time, rather than trying to do it individually.

`ls -lah` for /Users gives

```
drwxr-xr-x    7 root      admin    238B 23 Oct 18:45 .
drwxr-xr-x@  44 root      wheel    1.5K  9 Mar 13:04 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root      wheel      0B 22 Aug  2015 .localized
drwxr-xr-x+  11 Guest     _guest   374B 23 Oct 18:45 Guest
drwxrwxrwt@  48 root      wheel    1.6K 13 Jan 09:28 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+  14 aUser     staff    476B  5 Aug  2015  aUser
```